# Make a Cronjob to Repeatedly Query MongoDB for New Data Since Last Query

Tags: json, mongodb, cron

My data provider has a remote instance of MongoDB with my data, which I can access via SSH. Currently, I query MongoDB using the command

`mongoexport  -d database -c collection --csv --out result.csv --q '{"date":{"$gte":new Date(1338480000000),"$lte": new Date(1338915599000)}}'`

and I from there I've been using WinSCP to transfer a copy of the resulting JSON file from the remote linux shell to my local Windows laptop.

The problem is that from now on I ideally need to have it automatically run the export every time a new entry ("event") is added to MongoDB *and* it has to automatically SCP or otherwise push the resulting JSON files to a company linux VPS. This is what a CS-guy in my company called an "event-driven export". I have no clue how to do that, nor does the data provider and I haven't been able to figure it out by Google-ing.

If it's not possible then I would settle for having the cronjob run every 1 minute and export the last 1 minute's worth of data from MongoDB as a JSON file, then SCP that file to my company's linux server. I could really use some help figuring how how to write the query as well as how to make mongoexport save the filenames sequentially (to avoid overwriting the same file) then tell SCP to send a copy of whatever the most recent was.

Comment: Maybe mongoexport isn't the best command for this kind of export? I've been looking at some alternatives but so far none of them support an "event-driven" export as described in my post.

Answer (score 0):

"Event driven export" would be a quite complicated thing, as the event (data was inserted) would have to be detected on the data provider side and then a notification sent to your company linux system.

Event detection would possibly mean a survey of the MongoDB log file (tail -f), which is not very reliable - what, if the detector fails and has to be restarted?

The probably easiest solution would be to run a MongoDB client on your company linux system that connects to the database at the data provider and periodically checks for new data (by checking the latest "date" entry). It would then get the new data directly, instead of the cumbersome export mechanism.

This survey client program could either be waiting (sleeping) in a permanent loop or be started by cron at regular intervals.